# Using reflection in custom enumerations to get possible values

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I'm working on some code that uses custom enumerations to ensure completeness checking and it needs to use reflection to get the list of possible values. Some code like the following is already in the codebase (everything that is not relevant is stripped out and/or renamed) I have put it all together into a standalone runnable format.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

object ReflectionUtil {

  def modules[A : TypeTag](parent: Any) = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror, universe}
    val members = currentMirror.classSymbol(parent.getClass).toType.members
      .filter{ symbol =>
        println(s"$symbol: ${symbol.typeSignature} <:< ${universe.typeOf[A]} is ${symbol.typeSignature <:< universe.typeOf[A]}")
        symbol.typeSignature <:< universe.typeOf[A]
      }
  }
}

trait Enumeration {
  type Value <: V

  protected[this] trait V

  lazy val values = ReflectionUtil.modules[V](this)
}

object Switch extends Enumeration {
  sealed trait Value extends V
  case object On extends Value
  case object Off extends Value
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(Switch.values)
}
```

The issue here is the line `symbol.typeSignature <:< universe.typeOf[A]` which returns false for everything that comes up, which you can see in the output:

```
object Off: Switch.Off.type <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
object On: Switch.On.type <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
constructor Switch: ()Switch.type <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
value values: => scala.Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
trait V: scala.AnyRef {

} <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method $init$: ()scala.Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method $asInstanceOf: [T0]()T0 <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method $isInstanceOf: [T0]()Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method synchronized: [T0](x$1: T0)T0 <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method ##: ()Int <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method !=: (x$1: Any)Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method ==: (x$1: Any)Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method ne: (x$1: AnyRef)Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method eq: (x$1: AnyRef)Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method notifyAll: ()Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method notify: ()Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method clone: ()java.lang.Object <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method getClass: ()java.lang.Class[_] <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method hashCode: ()Int <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method toString: ()java.lang.String <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method equals: (x$1: Any)Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method wait: ()Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method wait: (x$1: Long)Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method wait: (x$1: Long, x$2: Int)Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method finalize: ()Unit <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method asInstanceOf: [T0]=> T0 <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
method isInstanceOf: [T0]=> Boolean <:< Enumeration.this.V is false
()
```

Note the first two lines of the output.
Why is it always coming back false even for types that look like they should conform (the enumerated types I'm actually interested in) and what can I do to fix this?

To reiterate: what I am looking to get from `lazy val values` is the relevant enumerated case objects `On` and `Off` within `Switch` and this needs to be automated so it can work with lots of other enumerated types like it.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, I will answer my own question.

This is the code that works as expected:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

object ReflectionUtil {

  def modules[A : TypeTag](parent: Any): Iterable[A] = {
    val baseType = typeOf[A]
    for {
      symbol <- currentMirror.classSymbol(parent.getClass).toType.members
      if symbol.isModule && symbol.info.widen <:< baseType
    } yield currentMirror.reflectModule(symbol.asModule).instance.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}

trait EnumeratedValue

trait Enumeration {
  type Value <: EnumeratedValue

  lazy val values = ReflectionUtil.modules[EnumeratedValue](this)
}

object Switch extends Enumeration {
  sealed trait Value extends EnumeratedValue
  case object On extends Value
  case object Off extends Value
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(Switch.values)
}
```

As it turns out, since traits are embedded into the resulting class bytecode, inner traits are not the same across all classes that use the outer trait. Therefore it was checking for conformity to a different trait than what was actually passed in the function definition. By pulling out the relevant trait to be outside the `Enumeration` trait, the function can now properly resolve the trait, so it works as expected.